# ndk-build, C:\User\MyUser is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, windows, ndk-build

I have a first demo project like

[image]

When I try to run `ndk-build` on Window. I get the message

```
C:\Users\ThinkPad' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

In my `Enviroment Variable`, I already has a path `C:\Users\ThinkPad T490\Downloads\today\android-ndk-r21e` which I link to a folder (which I download from [developer.android.com/ndk/downloads](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads))

No clear error appears so I don't know how to fix. What should I do to make `ndk-build` work

Answer (score 0):

My `ndk` envirorment path contains a space so I go the above error.
Move `ndk` to a path that doesn't contain space solve problem